# Using await in code for a child process will make only that child process or all the other child process for execution?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-cluster

I am using await in code for one of my child processes. So when this is executed, will all others child processes halt their execution or will only this child process will halt?

I am using `cluster.fork` and `await` in code is for my child processes.

Comment: What exactly are you `await`ing? Did you manually construct a promise?

Answer (score 0):

No your `await` has no impact on other processes.

But you seem to have a misconception: Not only does `await` not block the other process you got using `cluster.fork`, but it doesn't either halt your current process.

The code after your `await` won't be executed until the passed promise is resolved but other promises might be resolved before this one, or other events may be produced by the underlying IO system, **even in the same process**.

Remember: node was able to handle concurrent requests even before the node cluster system.

Related: [Why node.js is fast when it's single threaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30638549/why-node-js-is-fast-when-its-single-threaded)